# How to get current URL in Open URL action in AutoControl Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I insert current URL in `<currentURL>` placeholder?

[image]

Thanks.

**Update**

Yes, it is possible, easily, using OPEN URL Action and using RUN SCRIPT Action: https://groups.google.com/g/autocontrol_app/c/QQPC-RSEBdM/m/T2-1QKGdAQAJ

Comment: Judging by the source code of the extension, there's no such thing. A workaround is to use its [scripting commands](https://www.autocontrol.app/scripting) ACtl.getTabInfo + ACtl.openURL.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, I posted an update